# Will my weigela come back?

Tags: diagnosis

I accidentally ran over my weigela with my riding mower. There is about 3 inches left. Will it come back or do I need to get a new one?

Answer (score 2):

It very likely will grow back, but it will take some time for it to recover. If its a young but established plant, it will have more chance of recovery, and more quickly than a recently planted or an old, mature plant. If the stems you have left are chewed up by the mower, cut them off cleanly with a sharp pair of secateurs or loppers. You don't say where you are, but in the northern hemisphere, you can rake in a handful or two of general purpose fertilizer in granular form around the base (such as Growmore) immediately, which will assist its recovery.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I will absolutely try your suggestions. I am in Saskatchewan, Canada. I appreciate you taking time to reply

Answer (score 0):

Is your shrub growing in grass? If yes, keep a circle of at least 1m diameter around the weigela weed and grass free. That way (a) the weigela won't be competing with grass/weeds for water and nutrients, (b) there's less chance of you damaging the shrub when you're cutting the grass, and (c) you won't be walking on adjacent soil and compacting it to the detriment of the weigela.

Comment: My weigela is in a garden ( the garden spot had high weeds I was mowing -to get control of them - when I accidentally ran over my weigela). The weigela has about a foot radius of cedar mulch all around it about 4-6 inches deep. There are still a few short branches that were laying on the ground and weren’t cut off.  Thanks for your reply